# Insert object using java client 6.5

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to insert an object using java high level rest client.

My mapping is the following:

```
"images":{
           "type":"nested",
           "properties":{
              "name":{
                  "type":"text"
              },
              "url":{
                 "type":"text"
              }
           }
        }
```

and java code:

> //productDb.getImages() returns ArrayList of type Image: with attributes "name" and "url"

```
productToIndex.put("images", new Gson().toJson(productDb.getImages()));
      IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest(ProductIndex.PRODUCT_INDEX, ProductIndex.TYPE)
                    .source(productToIndex, XContentType.JSON);
            try {              
                restHighLevelClient.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);              
            } catch (Exception e) {
                logger.error("Data access error occured the entity persistence...", e);
                throw new Exception(e);
            }
```

The error is:

ElasticsearchStatusException[Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [images] tried to parse field [images] as object, but found a concrete value]]

The concrete value:

```
images -> [{"name":"Capture.PNG","url":"/api/trader/files/2132132/Capture.PNG"},{"name":"payement.jpg","url":"/api/trader/files/31231321/payement.jpg"}]
```

==> For me it seems Okay and I cannot understand why it returns an exception, if I replace productDb.getImages() with new Arraylist<>(); it works fine (indexed value is: "images": [])

I cannot find an example of how to index arrays object using java, is there a solution to do it ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you notice there is a difference in what format ES expects your JSON and in what format you are sending the payload.

**Right format of nested document for index**

```
{
    "images": [ --> note image array
        {
            "name": "opster.PNG",
            "url": "/api/trader/files/2132132/Capture.PNG"
        },
        {
            "name": "data.jpg",
            "url": "/api/trader/files/31231321/payement.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

**JSON which you java code generated, note there is no images key**

```
{
  "name": "Capture.PNG",
  "url": "/api/trader/files/2132132/Capture.PNG"
},
{
  "name": "payement.jpg",
  "url": "/api/trader/files/31231321/payement.jpg"
}
```

As Elasticsearch is not able to find the `images` key and yours is not a valid JSON array, Elasticsearch is throwing the error:

### Solution:

Please send the JSON mentioned in the begining and then use the below code to convert it in a proper format.

```
public void saveToEs(NestedImages nestedImages) throws IOException {
        ObjectMapper Obj = new ObjectMapper();
        final String images = Obj.writeValueAsString(nestedImages);
        final IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("nestedimage")
                .source(images, XContentType.JSON);
        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);

    }
```

Important links for [nested data type index def and indexing example](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html#nested-fields-array-objects) and [REST high-level indexing java code](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-index.html).

Comment: Thank you, yes, I have tried also this solution, the code is the following:
 ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
 String images = mapper.writeValueAsString(productDb.getImages());
 productToIndex.put(ProductIndex.IMAGES, images);

productToIndex is a HashMap, with key= images and value =  [{"name":"Capture.PNG","url":"/api/trader/files/kjghk/Capture.PNG"},{"name":"payement.jpg","url":"/api/trader/files/kjghk/payement.jpg"}]

But it doesn't work.

Comment: @Nicolas, can you debug you code and inspect the JSON just before sending it to ES? if its not in the format i provided in the begining it would fail

Comment: This code resolves my problem: 

 List<Map<String, String>> images = new ArrayList<>();
        productDb.getImages().stream().forEach(image -> {
            Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
            map.put(ProductIndex.IMAGE_NAME, image.getName());
            map.put(ProductIndex.IMAGE_URL, image.getUrl());
            images.add(map);
        });


Thank you !